# Remove automated closing bracket comments in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, dart, flutter

I'm seeing following happen when working in intelliJ IDEA with Dart based project

[image]

All comments there i.e `// AppBar` are auto generated, I assume for easier tracking of what closing brackets belong where. Weird bit is that I can't even highlight them, nor delete them and when I copy code they are not copied over.

Is there a way to disable this feature in the ide?

Comment: I haven't seen anything about disabling. You could create an issue in the bug tracker of the IDE like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com. It's similar to syntax highlighting. These comments are not saved to the file, only shown. Actually I also find them somewhat annoying and not too useful.

Comment: Now also available in Android Studio (since 3.1)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The checkbox is in Settings (Preferences) | Editor | General | Appearance, toggle 'Show closing labels in Dart source code'.

Comment: Changing this setting only applies after restarting the IDE, so be sure to do that.

Comment: Is there any way to do the opposite: enable it for javascript / JSX code?

Comment: Changes applied without restarting IDE for me. IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 Ultimate, May 28, 2019.

Comment: Note that you need to re-open the file, this annoyed me for a few minutes.

Comment: You don't have to do a restart ..... only closing the window and reopen it works!

Answer (score 1):

And in the vs code editor, change this setting to false

```
"dart.closingLabels": true
```

You can find this setting easily. Go setting and search(Ctrl+f) dart.closingLabels

#### Update 24.11.2019:

If you want to customize the closing label color, you can do this. In vscode, open your `settings.json` file and set this setting

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "dart.closingLabels": "#FF5733"
 },
```

Comment: Thanks, I prefer VSC over IDE so that was for me :<)

Comment: @Mahi see updated answer, you can customize your closing labels too. I also prefer vscode instead of android studio or Intelij