# Is there a way to add automated closing bracket comments in IntelliJ IDEA for Java?

Tags: intellij-idea, tags, settings

I'm looking for a way to add automatic comments to closing brackets for Java in IntelliJ

I see that there is something similar for Dart in IntelliJ discussed here [Remove automated closing bracket comments in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47962237/remove-automated-closing-bracket-comments-in-intellij-idea)

Does anyone know if there is something similar for Java?

Comment: Not at the moment, feature request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: I was wondering about the same for javascript/JSX